# Route getting GET value passed via a href in Laravel 5.2

Tags: routes, laravel-5, anchor

Dear all nice people here,

I am making an ecommerce platform using Laravel 5.2 (very new to it) and I would like to make a anchor tag where when you click it passes a GET value to the route. it actually goes to the link below
http://localhost:8000/products/803160151?product_choice_id=1
but with a 404 page instead. I guess it is that I wrote the route function in a wrong way? Please find my codes below for your reference and let me know if you need more information on whatever. Thanks.

routes.php

```
Route::get('products/{product_code}?product_choice_id={product_choice_id}', function($product_code, $product_choice_id){
      $product = Product::where('product_code',$product_code)->firstOrFail();
    $product_choice = Product_Choice::where('id', $product_choice_id)->get();
    $reviews = Review::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();
    $stars = Review::where('product_id', $product->id)->pluck('stars');    
    if(count($stars)){
        $total_stars = collect($stars)->sum()/count($stars);
        }   else {
            $total_stars = "not rated yet";
        };
    return view('products.details')
        ->with('product', $product)
        ->with('product_choice',$product_choice)
        ->with('reviews',$reviews)
        ->with('stars',$stars)
        ->with('total_stars',$total_stars);
});
```

interface.blade.php

```
    @php
      $product_choice = App\Product_Choice::where('product_id',$product->id)->where('default',1)->firstOrFail()
    @endphp

<a class="aa-product-img" href="{{ url('/products').'/'.$product->product_code.'?product_choice_id='.$product_choice->id }}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define the parameters. Just define the route

```
Route::get('prdoucts/{product_code}', function(Request $request) {
    $product_choice_id = $request->input('product_choice_id');
});
```

Dont forget to add

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Within the request you will find all the GET parameters. This will also work for post / put / patch / delete - ofcourse you will need to define the route to use these methods

Comment: so the anchor tag stays the same?

Comment: yes it can, even though it's not actually useful to use the url command here.

Comment: thanks for your answer and it did help me. i got confused with some concepts and you made it easy now. However, what do you mean by not useful to use url command here?